# Bit reversing in Python

Tags: python

Given a number, such as `2`, how would I reverse the bits assuming it is represented in 32-bits?

Take 1 for example, as unsigned 32-bits is 00000000000000000000000000000001 and doing the flipping we get 11111111111111111111111111111110 which in turn is 4294967294

I've tried the following but it is not working.

```
numElements = int(raw_input())
for i in range(0,numElements):
    x = int(raw_input())
    print int(bin(x)[:1:-1], 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XOR against a number with all 32 bits set to one:

```
mask = 2 ** 32 - 1
x = int(raw_input())
print format(x ^ mask, '032b')
```

`^` is the [bitwise XOR operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

I used the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to produce a 0-padded 32-bit binary representation, it is far more flexible than `bin()`.

Demo:

```
>>> mask = 2 ** 32 - 1
>>> format(mask, '032b')
'11111111111111111111111111111111'
>>> x = 1
>>> x ^ mask
4294967294
>>> format(x ^ mask, '032b')
'11111111111111111111111111111110'
```